# serilog on ElasticsearchSinkOptions mapper_parsing_exception

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

when try to use elastic search with serilog show me this error on log some data
Failed to store event with template 'HttpClient Request: {RequestName} {@Request}' into Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch reports for index logs the following: {"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [fields.Request] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"}

how ignore null value when Serialize to Json or how change Serializer with custom options?

did not find any example for custom serialize on elasticsearch